# PrintWriter in Java, Can't find file error

Tags: java, macos, printwriter

I need to use PrintWriter in Java to read a document saved on the computer and print it into an array.  We must use a skeleton and develop our code from that.  I think I understand the concept, except the compiler keeps telling me the file does not exist.  I think the problem may be that I have an iMac and it does not have c drive, at least not labeled that way.  What am I doing wrong?  I included the code in my code so far...

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class pWriter{

    public static void main(String[]args) throws Exception{

        Scanner stdln = new Scanner(new File("c://FileName.txt));

        String[] line = new String[238];

        while (stdln.hasNextLine()){
            int i = 0;
            line[i] = stdln.nextLine();
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try `new File(".").getAbsolutePath()` to see the absolute path and update your file path based on that.

Comment: Yes, not having a file called "c://FileName.txt" on your iMac would be a problem. You need to find out the correct filename.

Comment: Compiler can't tell you that file doesn't exist, because compiler doesn't run your code. Compiler may inform you that you have errors in code like in your didn't close `"c://FileName.txt` String (you forgot to add `"` after it). Also are you sure that there should be `//` in your path (I suspect that you may want to use `/` or ``\\`` instead)?

Comment: the . in new File(".") is the file name?

Comment: "." is a directory. That is just for test purpose so you can fix up your real path to the file.

Comment: I think this is just a typo error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`PrintWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) is for output. [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) can be used for input. And you aren't closing your String literal,

```
// "c:/FileName.txt" // <-- one slash and a quote at the end.
File f = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "fileName.txt");
```

For `fileName.txt` in your home folder.

I think you meant to declare `i` outside the loop, you could also use a [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) like

```
File f = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "fileName.txt");
try (Scanner stdln = new Scanner(f)) {
    String[] line = new String[238];
    int i = 0; // <-- outside the loop.
    while (stdln.hasNextLine()){
        line[i] = stdln.nextLine();
        i++;
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much to all of you, I am not sure what I did, but when I used this code File f = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "fileName.txt"); it now can find the file.  Thank you so much.

Comment: @user320087 "c://FileName.txt" is not a valid path on a mac, and it would only be valid in Windows if there was a file with that name in the root of the c volume. In contrast, the user.home system property gets the user's home directory and that constructor is [`File(File parent, String child)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 0):

First you need to find the real path to your input file. For example, if it is in your home directory, it could be: "/Users/yourusername/FileName.txt"

Then you need to fix your while loop from this:

```
while (stdln.hasNextLine()){
    int i = 0;
    line[i] = stdln.nextLine();
    i++;
}
```

to this:

```
int i = 0;
while (stdln.hasNextLine()){
    line[i] = stdln.nextLine();
    i++;
}
```

Then you need to print your array of lines.

Comment: Thanks for the hint about the loop too, I didn't see that error.